# Doctrine cascade to subobjects with OneToMany Relation

Tags: doctrine-orm, one-to-many, cascade

I'm having some trouble to persist and object with an owning sub-object. More specifically I have an User class which owns at least one PGPKey object.

The following code snippet fails:

```php
$user = new User("username","password");
$em->persist($user);
```

with the error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'PGPKeys.owner' cannot be null

The Problem to me is as follows:
The User.idUser field, which corresponds to the PGPKey.owner is a GeneratedValue and thus still undefined at the time when persist is called. Then Doctrine tries to save the PGPKey first but the SQL does not allow owner to be null. If the User would be saved first the generated id could be used to save to the owner field of the PGPkey.

I would have expected that Doctrine saved the owning object before the owned, but that doesn't seem to be the case or I'm missing something.

User.postPersist() is never executed.

User.php

```php
/**
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @Entity
 */
class user {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false, columnDefinition="int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT");
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $idUser;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", nullable=false, columnDefinition="VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL")
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="PGPKey", mappedBy="owner", cascade={"persist","remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @var PGPKey[]
     */
    protected $PGPKeys;

    public function __construct($username,$password)
    {
        $this->PGPKeys = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->setPassword($password);
    }

    /** @PostPersist */
    public function postPersist(){
        foreach ($this->PGPKeys as $key)
        {
            $key->setOwner($this->getId());
        }
    }
    public function setPassword($newPassword, $oldPassword = false)
    {
        if ($oldPassword === false || !count($this->PGPKeys))
        {
            $newkey = new PGPKey($newPassword);
            $newkey->setOwner($this->idUser);
            $this->PGPKeys[] = $newkey;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->PGPKeys[count($this->PGPKeys) - 1]->changePassword($oldPassword, $newPassword);
        }
    }
}
```

PGPKey.php

```php
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class PGPKey
{

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", unique=true, columnDefinition="int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT");
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $idKey;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer", columnDefinition="int(11) unsigned NOT NULL");
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="PGPKeys");
     */
    protected $owner;

    public function __construct($password)
    {
        //do RSA stuff
    }

    public function setOwner($ownerid)
    {
        $this->owner = $ownerid;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After chatting with someone on doctrine IRC I can finally present a solution:

In class PGPKey instead of

```php
/**
 * @Column(type="integer", columnDefinition="int(11) unsigned NOT NULL");
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="PGPKeys");
 */
protected $owner;
public function setOwner($ownerid)
{
    $this->owner = $ownerid;
    return $this;
}
```

it should read

```php
/**
 * @var User
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="PGPKeys");
 * @JoinColumn(name="owner", referencedColumnName="idUser")
 */
protected $owner;

public function setOwner(User $owner)
{
    $this->owner = $owner;
    return $this;
}
```

So the property has to be defined as a JoinColumn and you have to reference to the whole owner object, not just the id. Doctrine will then extract the id from the user using the info from the JoinColumn annotation. This way the User is stored first to the database, given an automatic id and this id is passed to the PGPKey subobject when executing

```php
$user = new User("username","password");
$em->persist($user)
```

Hope this helps others as well.